# Cannot open https://www.rba.gov.au from Windows 2012

Tags: networking, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2

We have an application that downloads https://www.rba.gov.au/rss/rss-cb-exchange-rates.xml daily to get exchange rates. It stopped working a few days ago, we found that above URL doesn't open in IE while it does in Chrome.
My understanding is that the App, which is developed using .NET framework, would certainly use the same thing under the hood as IE, thus it couldn't download the file either.
Below is the error I get when visiting the site using IE, I'm sure that all TLS version are enabled:
[image]

And below is the error I get when I try to download the file through powershell/.net:
[image]

Then I tested the url using ssllabs.com and got the following result. It says fatal error is ruturned if client is IE11/Win 8 (I believe Windows 2012 and Windows 8 belong to the same family, so fatal error would occur to server 2012 too).
[image]

But I'm thinking there must be something I can do, some setting I can change to fix this issue? I would like to avoid Upgrading the OS to server 2016 just for this issue. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it is a cross-post to [this question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1536827/cannot-open-https-www-rba-gov-au-from-windows-2012) and is already answered there.

Comment: I think this question better fits here than on Super User, though. The solution of using Firefox or Chrome is a Super User approach, and not ideal for such a small automation task as this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Reserve Bank of Australia has chosen to only support TLS 1.2 connections with strong cipher suites:

- `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)`
- `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)`

Despite Windows 2012 R2 with IE11 supports TLS 1.2, it doesn't support these cipher suites.

If you want to avoid upgrading to Windows Server 2016/2019, you could use some 3rd party tools for downloading the file, like [curl for Windows](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/) (the current version 7.69.1 comes with OpenSSL 1.1.1d).

```
curl -o exchange-rates.xml "https://www.rba.gov.au/rss/rss-cb-exchange-rates.xml"
```

Now, your .NET application can use the local copy of the XML file, instead.